# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I write my app on Next.js. I get data from API. When I click on page "About" (below) I have error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, but when I restart this page - it works.
How I can avoid this mistake?

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import Link from 'next/link'
import axios from 'axios';

export default class extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps () {
    if(!process.browser) {
      const res = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=2cdce3bbe05c745f380ca0af5874a2d8&language=en-US&page=1')
      return {data: res.data}
    } else {
      return {data: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('bpl'))}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    if(!sessionStorage.getItem('bpl')) sessionStorage.setItem('bpl', JSON.stringify(this.props.data))
  }
  render () {

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />

        <div className="pure-g">
            <div className="pure-u-1-3"></div>
            <div className="pure-u-1-3">
              <h1>TOP Movies 2017</h1>

              <table className="pure-table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Popularity</th>
                    <th>Overview</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.data.results.map((results, id) => {

                  return (
                      <tr key={id} >
                        <td className="title"><p className="title_sign">{results.title}</p></td>
                        <td>{results.popularity}</td>
                        <td>{results.overview}</td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                })}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div className="pure-u-1-3"></div>
        </div>
        <style jsx>{`
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 40px;
            color: grey;
        }
      .title {
        width: 180px;
      }
      .title_sign {
        font-weight: 600;
      }
      th {
        color: grey;
      }
    `}</style>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: put the condition on `data.result` like this: `this.props.data && this.props.data.result && this.props.data.results.map(.....`

Comment: `this.props.data.results` is undefined, don't do a map on it before you are sure the data is available, eg `this.props.data && this.props.data.results && this.props.data.results.map(...)`

Comment: @Icepickle, unfourtunately, it still works only after I restart the page.

Comment: Valeria, are you then sure `res.data` is always available and filled? What about your if statement? Or your potential empty sessionStorage?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you storing received data in props. Props are supposed to be static and passed down from parent component.  If your component is changing visual form based on received data then you are suppose to store it in state. Component can not modify it's own props. What I see is you are trying to update component's props. Better you set state for received data. And use state to iterate in render method.

Make sure to use "object &&" while using maps on javascript object.